# Отображение контента по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сразу скажу, что AJAX применять здесь не хотелось бы.

Имеется 10 блоков с контентом. Изначально показаны 2 блока и кнопка "Показать еще". По нажатию на кнопку нужно сделать, чтобы появлялись еще два следующих блока. Нажав еще раз, должны появиться еще 2 блока (6/10), как только отображены 10 из 10 блоков, кнопка "Показать еще" пропадает. Как это можно реализовать на javascrip (jquery)?

Javacript(jQuery) код:

```
$(".show-more").click(function(){  
    $(document).find(".more_service").slideToggle();
    $(".show-more").css("display","none");
})
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/4qvsadud/1/) (используется 4 блока)

Comment: Так а чем Вам не подходит тот вариант, что в примере? Просто вместо 4 блоков, делаете 10.... В чем проблема?

Comment: Данный вариант мне не совсем подходит, т.к. он отображает сразу все скрытые блоки по нажатию на кнопку. И я не знаю как его доработать чтобы он добавлял по нажатию по 2 блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать тот код, что в приведенном Вами примере с небольшими изменениями.
Делаете все точно также, как там, только вместо двух скрытых блоков, делаете 8 (ну или сколько Вам надо). И чуть меняете javascript:

```
$(".show-more").click(function(){
    $(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible):lt(2)").slideToggle('fast',
        function() {
            if ($(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").length==0) {
                $(".show-more").css("display","none");
            }
        }
    );
})
```

Изменения: `.find(".more_service:not(:visible):lt(2)").` - ищет все скрытые (`:not(:visible)`) элементы с классом `.more_service` и берет только первые два из найденных (`:lt(2)`)

Чтобы кнопка 'Показать еще' удалялась, когда больше нечего показать, Вам надо создать callback функцию, которая запустится, когда `slideDown()` закончится. Функция прячет кнопку, если невидимых элементов - ноль (`.find(".more_service:not(:visible)").length`)

Comment: Благодарю Вас, не знал даже что так можно, единственная беда в том, что кнопка "Показать еще" пропадает после первого нажатия (это понятно почему происходит), но как сделать чтобы она пропадала, когда все блоки отображены? Нужно вводить для этого переменную и вычислять кол-во блоков?

Comment: я изменил ответ... добавил нужный функционал. посмотрите

Comment: Вроде работает как надо, благодарю Вас!